# Help understanding this excerpt

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for some help understanding the four lines in bold below. The general context of the conversation is that Person 2 has asked everyone to leave him and 沖田 alone together for the day as 沖田 said she wanted to spend the day with him. As he is seeing two of his friends off the following conversation occurs:

> Person 1「二人きりになりたいからとか、あんたからそんな言葉が聞けるようになるとはねー」
>
> Person 2「べ、別にそういったやましい気持ちはなくてさ…」
>
> Person 1「あれー、おかしいなー。あたしは別にどんな気持ちとか言ってないんだけどなー。」
>
> Person 3「どういう経緯であれ、沖田が心底信頼してんだ。それでいいじゃねぇか。」
>
> Person 1「ぶぅ…べっつにいいですけどー。」
>
> Person 2「なに、ぶーたれてんだよ。」
>
> **Person 1「沖田ちゃんだって女の子なんだから、そういうの気にしてもいいと思っただけだもん。」**
>
> **Person 3「まぁ、あいつはそういうの考えたこともなかっただろうからなぁ。」**
>
> **Person 2「だ、だから僕だっていうのか？」**
>
> **Person 1「鈍感気取ってるモヤシ眼鏡は置いて、買い物いこう」**

My understanding of the lines before it is that Person 1 jokes and implies that he has something else in mind and not just to spend time together, which he refutes.

My understanding of the lines in bold are:

「沖田ちゃんだって女の子なんだから、そういうの気にしてもいいと思っただけだもん。」- I think she is saying that 沖田 is a girl, so Person 2 should be more conciously aware/thinking about these things.

「まぁ、あいつはそういうの考えたこともなかっただろうからなぁ。」 - I think he is saying that he doesn't think that Person 2 has thought about those things(following on from previous speaker)

「だ、だから僕だっていうのか？」 - I'm not quite sure what he means by this line.

「鈍感気取ってるモヤシ眼鏡は置いて、買い物いこう」- Let's leave Mr insensitive/oblivious wimpy four-eyes and go shopping.

Answer (score 2):

「沖田ちゃんだって女の子なんだから、そういうの気にしてもいいと思っただけだもん。」is that "沖田 is a girl, so **she(沖田)** should be more consciously aware/thinking about that kind of things.

「まぁ、あいつはそういうの考えたこともなかっただろうからなぁ。」is that "I think that **she(沖田)** had never thought about that kind of things,"

「だ、だから僕だっていうのか？」means "Did **she(沖田**) choose me because of that?"

沖田 doesn't seem to think of Person2 as a man who approaches her.